# Adding custom data source to multilist with search field not working

Tags: fieldtype, datasource, field

After creating a class to get desired sorted items to populate list, after making sure to type in the source correctly in the source field as code:namespace.classname, assemblyname , still results didn't come up as expected, any idea what am i missing ? is there is any config files to be added for the class for example?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. The field you are using is to provide a Sitecore Content Tree path. Are you creating any custom control or working in OOTB?

Comment: OOTB
my reference :
https://sitecoretweaks.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/custom-collection-of-items-in-sitecore-multilist-field-datasource/

Comment: Can you check if you are able to debug your method?

Comment: checked already, I can't ,tried multiple times but my breakpoint not being hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you are following is working with the `Multilist field`, not with the `Multilist with Search`.

I have checked this using this class.

```
namespace TEST.Foundation.Common.CustomSitecore
{
    public class Multilist: IDataSource
    {
        public Item[] ListQuery(Item item)
        {
            item = SitecoreData.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
        return item.Axes.GetDescendants().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I used in Sitecore

[image]

Comment: Perfect you're quite right, thank you so much